# jQuery change function for both radio and checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I do something when a radio button in a specific group OR a checkbox in a specific group has changed?

```
$("input[name=radiogroupname]") && "input[name=checkboxgroupname]").change(function () {
    //do something when any of them has changed
});
```

Comment: `$("input[name=radiogroupname], input[name=checkboxgroupname]")`

Comment: [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

Comment: Oh it's that easy, thank you. I was trying this before and it didn't work. Maybe I forgot to remove that bracket

Comment: could you please response to the answer so that i can know it is working for you.

Comment: Any reason for down vote?

Comment: Guys please leave comment when you down vote so that it is easy to find the mistakes.

Comment: @AKA DV wasn't mine, but please don't bother answering duplicates. All it does is prevent the garbage collector from deleting this question.

Comment: I understand - I do the same myself sometimes, without checking for a dupe first. The DV is a little harsh IMO, but that's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: They should rather appreciate the answer as it was given so spontaneously at the same time when it was marked duplicate and answer button was removed

Comment: If you think i am correct you can have a UV to me so that it get balanced. I really don't like the DV when the answer seems to be ok